# AWS S3 Bucket Accessible from my ElasticBeanStalk Instance only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 1 s3 bucket, 1 elasticbeanstalk instance. Currenly my s3bucket is made public hence its accessible from any domain, even from my localhost. 
     I want that all my s3 bucket resources should be accessible from my EBS instance only where my APP is hosted/running. My app should be able to view these resources and upload new images/resources to this bucket .
     I am sure somebody myt have done this.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling access to S3 has several ways. The best practice to make something privately accessible is: not to give any rights to access your S3 buckets/files in the bucket policy.

However you should create an IAM role which has either a full access to S3, or limited access to some actions, some buckets.

For every EC2 instances and also to every Elastic Beanstalk environments, you can attache an IAM Role. This role will be automatically served to your instances via instance metadata. This is a safe way to give special rights to your instances.

(Note: This is an AWS security best practice, since AWS will deal with the key rotations on your EC2 boxes.)

Comment: I understand the point of IAM but to access a S3 resource via url e.g.  <<s3bucket host name>>/my-images/imagefile.jpg ... from my app hosted on EBS. which can be like www.xyz.com .. now within this app i have <img src ="<<s3bucket host name>>/my-images/imagefile.jpg " /> .. So where is the role of IAM? here.. Or do I need some CORS setting?

Comment: The problem is, that your question was asking a completely different thing. If you are sending HTML to your user with an IMG tag, then the file will be downloaded by the browser. If it's a direct S3 link, then it will go directly to S3, not via your instances. ( Thats the point of using S3.) The best practice to restrict public access on S3 is signed URL-s. This will give temporary URL-s to every user. But using signed URL-s for a lot's of files may costs you a lots of money/resource.

Comment: Hi Adam,   Could you suggest a policy sample in which bucket images can be accessible only from my app deployed on EBS.

Comment: @user3112954 you could configure a drive mapping to the s3 bucket and symlinks.